# sql server 2012 grid result copy/pasted into excel 2010

Tags: sql-server-2012, excel-2010

so I just got for the first time that issue and it is too late to run the query again.

the issue is the character return of a varchar field is actually doing a new row in excel so my copy/paste is screwed big time.

I think i have a solution but I would like to know if someone else have another solution

my solution is creating a little script that will find the "incorrect" row and move the content at the proper place

any better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how i fixed my issue (code specific to my issue)

```
Sub test()


Dim cell As Range
Dim lastGoodRow As Range
For Each cell In Range("a1:a1938")

If IsNumeric(cell.Text) Then
    Set lastGoodRow = Range("v" & cell.Row)
End If

If Not IsNumeric(cell.Text) Then
    lastGoodRow.Value = lastGoodRow.Text & vbCrLf & cell.Text
    If Range("b" & cell.Row).Text <> "" Then
    Range("B" & cell.Row & ":J" & cell.Row).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("W" & lastGoodRow.Row).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```